# Material UI Table Searching is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rQO2.png)

if i search for the name on the 2 page (i.e. 6-10th row and so on ) Then the corresponding data is not showing although it is showing on if i click back to 1st Page(i.e 1-5th row)